# HTML image not loading , and I cannot find what is problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, image

I tried to load an image file on the HTML code, but it doesn't work like this.

[image]

HTML code 'index.js' is

```html
<div id="myArea">
  <img src="../public/images/image.png" height="50px" width="50px">
</div>
```

To solve this problem I checked these items

1. directory path

```
[public]
  [images]
  |__ image.png
[routes]
[views]
  |__ index.js
app.js
```

2. image file is 'image.png' , not 'image.PNG'
3. I already checked the image file but there's no problem with it.
   Also, I cannot load other image files by using this HTML codes.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe change the path to `/public/images/image.png`. `..` refers to the parent directory. Also please share your entire code.

Comment: Sorry... it doesn't work ...

Comment: Share the code for your app.js and index.js

Comment: can you post your app.js file as well? May be the problem is with the declaration of public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the public directory will be accessible from the root directory and there is no `/public` in real life applications, so you need to use absolute path here like this:

```html
<div id="myArea">
  <img src="/images/image.png" height="50px" width="50px">
</div>
```

**NOTE:** If you did not resolve your public directory in your `app.js`, you also may need to resolve it like this:

```js
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mess with the path:

```
./public/images/image.png
public/images/image.png
images/image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The same code works for me.
Will you able to open the image through browser?
Which path it is looking for the image?
when you refresh the browser you can see it in networks tab